# How to input a specific Pantone color number in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pantone, swatches

**Can someone please tell me the steps to input a Pantone number in Illustrator?**

For example, I have selected what I want to color, now I want to make that selection Pantone #300.  Where do I input that "#300" so that my selection now using that color?

I've looked all over the swatch panel and do not see how or where to do that.

Comment: Bobkap, I'm not too sure where you are stuck. Do you have issues finding where are the Pantone libraries and how to add them to your swatches in Illustrator? Or how to use a color from your swatches and colorize an element? Maybe this can get you started, I made a google search using the words  "how to add pantone in illustrator" and this guide seems like a good start for this: http://graphicdesign.spokanefalls.edu/tutorials/tech/pantone_colors/pantone.htm

Answer (score 4):

1. Open the `Swatches` palette.
2. Click on the palette's options icon in the top right (three horizontal bars with a tiny triangle next to them).
3. `Open Swatch Library > Color Books >` and choose either `Pantone+ Solid Coated` or `Pantone+ Solid Uncoated`. Actual books present may vary with your Illustrator version.
4. A separate swatches panel appears with all the swatches in the book. On top of the panel is a search function. Enter the number (*just* the number) in that field and your desired swatch will be selected.
5. (Optionally) Drag the swatch from the book to your `Swatches` palette and apply fur fun and profit.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know about the colorbooks, but I am not interested in opening different books – thats a no-go for me. I want to search ALL pantone colors. How do you do that? :)

Comment: @Jonas - the Pantone colour books already contain all the Pantone colours. You first need to decide if you want a coated or uncoated colour.  The colours in both books are actually the same ink mix, but will look different on coated or uncoated stock.